# css animation not triggering after media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-animations

i have a list that looks like this

```
<ul class="timeline-container">
   <li class="timeline-item-container">
       <div class="timeline-item></div>
   </li>
   <li class="timeline-item-container">
       <div class="timeline-item></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I declare the 2 animations

```
    @keyframes slideLeft
    {
        from {
            transform: translateX(1000px);
        }

        to {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes slideRight
    {
        from {
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
        }

        to {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }
```

Then on my css i have this:

```
.timeline-item
{
    animation: slideRight .6s ease both;

    @media (max-width:767px)
    {
        animation: slideLeft .6s ease both;
    }
}
```

So this works perfect, all the items in my list slide in from the right when the screen is smaller than 767px and from the left when its any bigger. when i resize the screen, the animation plays again.

Now i want every odd item in the list to slide in from the right when the screen is bigger than 767px so I add this:

```
.timeline-item-container:nth-child(even) .timeline-item
{
   @media (min-width:767px)
   {
        animation: slideLeft .6s ease both;
   }
}
```

This works if i refresh the page but if i resize the screen, the animation doesnt play. It should play the animation when the screen resizes like before

I know the animation is there because if i refresh it, it plays, just not after i resize the screen

Any help is appriciated

https://jsfiddle.net/7pk6yncd/

Comment: can you create  working example?

Comment: @TemaniAfif hi i have included a jsfiddle, as you can see the animation works correctly when its ran but when you resize, only 1 runs

Comment: it's working fine, If you resize the fiddle it's repeating

Comment: @TemaniAfif are you using chrome? maybe its just my computer. For me, the top bar is not animating at all when im resizing back and forth

Comment: ah, you want to trigger the same animation again?

Comment: yes, they should both come in from right to left when its small than the media query, and by default, the top should be left to right and visa versa from the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to define the same animation twice under different names. Actually the animation you are using is the same so the media query will not trigger it again.

```css
.box {
  background:red;

  animation:fromLeft 2s linear forwards;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
.box {
  background:blue;
  display:block;
  animation:fromLeft-alt 2s linear forwards;

}

}

@keyframes fromLeft {
   from {
     transform:translateX(-100%);
   }
}
@keyframes fromLeft-alt {
   from {
     transform:translateX(-100%);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some content
</div>
```

Comment: ah, this makes perfect sense, I can just define it as a different name, perfect, thankyou!

Answer (score -1):

You can  not place `@media` in css rule.

It works the other way, here you go:

```css
    .timeline-item
    {
        animation: slideRight .6s ease both;

    }

    @keyframes slideLeft
    {
        from {
            transform: translateX(1000px);
        }

        to {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes slideRight
    {
        from {
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
        }

        to {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }

    @media (max-width:767px)
    {
        .timeline-item{
            animation: slideLeft .6s ease both;
        }
        .timeline-item-container:nth-child(even) .timeline-item
        {
                animation: slideRight .6s ease both;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am using sass so media queries work inside classes. I have tried it outside and i still get the same issue.

Comment: @RachelDockter, ok. Sass is not dynamic. You won't be able to generate or animate CSS properties and values in real-time. But you can generate them in a more efficient way and let standard properties (CSS animation for example)

Comment: i think you can find more detail here: [https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/07/16/automating-css-animations-with-sass/](https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/07/16/automating-css-animations-with-sass)